Uneven thickness on curves with sharp turns
Im trying to make a railing for a boat using curve profiles, but whenever theres a turn greater than 45 degrees, the thickness starts becoming inconsistent.
I've seen solutions that suggest using 2D mode in the curve settings, this currently doesn't work for me as the railing has a slight curve on it that i want to keep.
This is what im trying to achieve in 3D mode.

This is the end result when not using 2D mode.


The reason why this happens is given in my answer here: Curve to Mesh bulges at intersection, the profile is oriented along the curve tangent. So when a curve makes a sharp 90° degree turn, the corner tangent has an angle of 45°, simply spoken. If the profile had a diameter of 1 on the vertical/horizontal curve, at the corner it would only be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ height and width in vertical and horizontal direction and therefore thinner than the rest. That's unfortunately how it works.

Is there any workaround for it?
